# Contact the team about/with/on/regarding this issue

Tags: prepositions

I understand there are always more than one way to say something but which preposition is correct in this sentence?

> Contact the team regarding/with/on/about this issue.

Comment: I would use either regarding or about. With and on are simply not grammatically correct in your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Contact the team about this issue** and **Contact the team regarding this issue** are both correct and work regardless of whether the issue is a topic or a problem.  You can contact the team *about* workplace rights or cancer, but you can't contact them "with" those things.  You can also contact the team *about* a bug in their software or *about* a problem you're having with their software.  In the last case, "with" would also be acceptable - though "about" might still be preferable.

**Contact the team with this issue** works if the issue is a problem whose details will be conveyed to the team.  (Compare "if you are the winner, contact us with your name and address" - "with" precedes the information to be conveyed to the team.)

***Contact the team on this issue** is wrong.  (You could "contact them on an old Nokia phone", but "on" here would mean "using".)